# PostgreSQL が動かない: could not connect to server

Tags: postgresql

macOS で PostgreSQL が動かない様です。

```sh
$ brew services list 
Name       Status  User         Plist
mysql      stopped 
postgresql error user /Users/user/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.postgresql.plist
```

因みに `psql -l` で PostgreSQL に接続できず、データベース一覧が取得できることを確認できません。

```sh
$ psql -l
psql: error: could not connect to server: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

類似質問もない様ですし、ググってもそれらしいものが見当たりません。

ヒントを下さると幸いです。

**追加作業**

```sh
$ brew services start postgresql 
==> Successfully started postgresql (label: homebrew.mxcl.postgresql) 

$ brew services list 
Name Status User Plist
mysql stopped
postgresql error XXXXXXX/Users/XXXXXXX/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.postgresql.plist　

postgres -D /usr/local/var/log/postgres.log 
postgres: could not access the server configuration file "/usr/local/var/log/postgres.log/postgresql.conf": Not a directory 

postgres -D /usr/local/var/postgres 
postgres: could not access the server configuration file "/usr/local/var/postgres/postgresql.conf": No such file or directory
```

```sh
$ pg_ctl -l /usr/local/var/postgres/server.log start
pg_ctl: no database directory specified and environment variable PGDATA unset Try "pg_ctl --help" for more information.
```

ログを確認

```
$ less /usr/local/var/log/postgres.log

it
2021-02-10 08:05:11.179 JST [615] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::1", port 54
32
2021-02-10 08:05:11.179 JST [615] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "127.0.0.1", port 5432
2021-02-10 08:05:11.224 JST [615] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432"
2021-02-10 08:05:11.921 JST [711] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2021-02-09 19:40:12 JST
2021-02-10 08:05:12.030 JST [615] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
2021-02-10 08:34:50.887 JST [615] LOG:  received smart shutdown request
2021-02-10 08:34:50.966 JST [615] LOG:  background worker "logical replication launcher" (PID 718) exited with exit code 1
2021-02-10 08:34:50.982 JST [713] LOG:  shutting down
2021-02-10 08:34:51.031 JST [615] LOG:  database system is shut down
2021-02-10 08:51:34.474 JST [1759] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 12.3 on x86_64-apple-darwin19.4.0, compiled by Apple clang version 11.0.3 (clang-1103.0.32.59), 64-bit
2021-02-10 08:51:34.476 JST [1759] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::1", port 5432
2021-02-10 08:51:34.476 JST [1759] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "127.0.0.1", port 5432
:
```

Comment: `/usr/local/var/log/postgres.log` にログがありそうです（IntelバイナリのHomebrewの場合）

Comment: ＞brew services stop postgresql で停止はすることは出来ます。
動かないのに停止できるとは、どういう意味ですか？ ＞Name Status User Plist mysql stopped postgresql error
mysqlがpostgresqlをstop
みたいなおかしなことになっています。
環境を見直して下さい。

Comment: 重複していて、かつ元からあったものと食い違っている内容を追記されると（どういう意図なのかわからず）混乱します。過不足ない状態に書き直したほうがいいかと思います。どれが正しいかは他の人には判断できないので、こちらで編集できません。

Comment: 申し訳ありません。修正致します。

Comment: $ pg_ctl -l /usr/local/var/postgres/server.log start
pg_ctl: no database directory specified and environment variable PGDATA unset
Try "pg_ctl --help" for more information.こんな感じでまだ解決していません。ここにヒントがあるような気がします。参考 http://tdall12.hatenablog.com/entry/2018/01/05/221657

Comment: 追加の情報は質問を [edit] して追記くださると幸いです。

Comment: `/usr/local/var/log/postgres.log` にログがあるというのは、単にファイルの中身を確認すれば良いのではないでしょうか。

Comment: ログがあるのかないのか書かない。ログがあるとして自分で見たのか見てないのか書かない。自分で見てないとしても質問に載せない。brew services list の結果が異なる物が2種類載っているのに間違っている方を消さない（その結果も改行の位置が疑わしい）。などを放っておいているので解決する気が無いのだと思ってました。

Comment: 本当に申し訳ありません。初学者と言えども、ルールを学んでから質問するべきだと感じます。

Comment: いくつか追記されていますが、実行したコマンドや表示されたファイル名よりも、コマンドの実行結果やファイルの中身の方が重要です。

Comment: cubickさんありがとうございます。この間やったことを記しておきます。*PostgreSQL をアンインストールしたくなったので、下の手順でやってみました。
* インストール済みの PostgreSQL バージョン確認
* brew uninstall –force で全てのバージョンをアンインストール
* PostgreSQL の設定ファイル、ログ、データなど諸々も削除
* 最後に PostgreSQL の再インストールはエラーです。

参考　https://codenote.net/mac/homebrew/3894.html

$ brew install postgresql
Error: 
  homebrew-core is a shallow clone.省略　Error: Permission denied @ rb_sysopen - /usr/local/var/homebrew/locks/postgresql.formula.lock　でエラーでした。

Comment: PostgreSQL アンインストールしてみたら、macの動作がおかしくなって、再起動を繰り返し、やむなく、time machin で復旧させました。参考　https://nektony.com/how-to/uninstall-postgresql-on-mac

Comment: qiita.com/hozmii/items/3617b67ea350f116ca3a　で手順通りやるが追加手順通り成功せず。

Answer (score 1):

取り敢えず `brew uninstall postgresql` を実行してみたが、次の様なエラーが出て試してみた。

```
$ sudo chown -R "$USER":admin /usr/local
```

を入力後PWを入れる。

```
$ brew uninstall postgresql
Uninstalling /usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/12.3_4... (3,220 files, 37.8MB)
postgresql  are still installed.
To remove all versions, run:
```

`$ brew uninstall --force postgresql` ⭐️これを実行してすべてクリーンにする。

`$ brew install postgresql` で再インストールするが、エラーが出る。

```
Error: 
  homebrew-core is a shallow clone.
To `brew update`, first run:

$ bundle install --path vendor/bundle
$ rails db:migrate
$ rails db:create
```

無事起動！

参考:

- [How to fix homebrew permissions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16432071/how-to-fix-homebrew-permissions)
- [ActiveRecord::NoDatabaseErrorが出た時の対処法](https://rails-ambassador.herokuapp.com/debugs/NoDatabaseError)